# jQuery dialog modal being removed before the dialog has finished closing

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm using the slide effect to show and hide a jQuery dialog.

This works well except that the `modal` (as in the overlay that covers the page) is removed as soon as I close the dialog, as opposed to when the dialog finally disappears from the screen.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
$('#login-preview-dialog').dialog({
    draggable: false,
    hide: 'slide',
    modal: true,
    show: 'slide',
    width: 500
});
```

**In reference to the answer provided by @Jai -**

I have updated my `dialog` call as suggested, but the model is still being removed as soon as I close the dialog.

Here is an image showing that even in the example this behavior is still occurring. You can see that the dialog is only partially closed, but that the modal has already been removed -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it this way:

[**jsbin link**](http://jsbin.com/akuDUPOh/1/edit)

---

```
$('#login-preview-dialog').dialog({
   draggable: false,
   show: {
      effect: "slide",
      duration: 500
   },
   hide: {
      effect: "slide",
      duration: 500
   }
   modal: true,
   width: 500//<------you can remove a "," trailing comma from here
});
```

[See this link for help](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make a difference. The modal (as in the overlay that covers the page) still disappears as soon as the 'X' is clicked.

Comment: [You can try this link](http://jsbin.com/akuDUPOh/2/edit) seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Nope, still the same I'm afraid. Literally as soon as you click the cross, the modal is removed. I've edited my question to show an image of it happening.